# how to exclude last row in every group by id in mysql?

Tags: mysql, window, row-number

the 3 columns are employee_id, month,salary. How to exclude last row in every employee_id group?

```
[1, 1, 20] 
[1, 2, 30] 
[1, 3, 40] 
[1, 4, 60] 
[1, 7, 90] 
[1, 8, 90]  #exclude

[2, 1, 20] 
[2, 2, 30] #exclude

[3, 2, 40] 
[3, 3, 60] 
[3, 4, 70] #exclude
```

My query adds rownumber, but then what can i do?

```
select 
id, month, salary, 
row_number()over(partition by id order by id) as ro #i tried this ,but how?


from employee 
order by id, month
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order by month DESC` in row number and then exclude 1 which corresponds to the most recent month for that id.

```
select id, month, salary 
from (
select 
id, month, salary, 
row_number()over(partition by id order by month desc) as ro 
from employee ) e
where ro > 1
order by id, month;
```

Answer (score 1):

For versions prior to 8.0, a correlated subquery can be used to do the trick.

```
select * From `table` t where not exists
(select id,max(`month`) mx from `table` group by id having t.id=id and t.`month`=mx) 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already 2 solutions, but I would like to show a third one, because the "row_number" solution is too complex and only works for mysql 8+ and the "where not exists" is very slow for large tables.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM your_table t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT grouping_column, MAX(ordering_column) AS max_order
FROM your_table
GROUP BY grouping_column
) t2 ON t1.grouping_column = t2.grouping_column AND t1.ordering_column < t2.max_order;
```

This solution joins a derived table calculating the max id of each group with the original table and selects only those rows which have a lower id than the derived result.